# OAuth2 for front end applications

Tags: android, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an application in which I need an authorization workflow.

I m working on OAuth2 with oauth2orize library.

My applications (client) are frontends written in javascript or java (android).

- First, what I need is simply a way to authenticate inside of them and get back an access token. To make it work, I have a resource owner flow.
  My problem is that I can't store my secret on my client app cause of security problems. Do you have an idea how should I do it?
- In the other hand, how can I make a third party login page? Like "connect trough XXX" and then be redirected on the login page?

Answer (score 1):

The [Implicit Grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) is for public clients operating on a given URL, like Javascript (and there's [a way to do it on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23262459/157328)).

You'll make a button "Connect through XXX" and then you redirect the user to XXX to authenticate. When that's done, you get a [redirect back](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2) with the Access Token in the URL fragment.